# Are PostgreSQL cursor bound to connection?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, cursors

I would like to confirm a point with PostgreSQL cursor.

I have to implement a select factory for huge result set query (more than 1Go of small-weight rows). Thus I have learn about cursor and I execute my query the following way:

I create a cursor:

```
DECLARE HashedCursorName CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM BigResultSetQuery;
```

I repetitively fetch small amount of resultset:

```
FETCH 1000 FROM HashedCursorName;
```

When resultset is exhausted I close the cursor:

```
CLOSE HashedCursorName;
```

I need to address concurrency, I mean, many users must be able to use the the same query stored in API procedure simultaneously. When a user execute a stored query, he receives a new connection. I first have mangled my cursor name in API because I thought that if all select query are called `StaticCursorName` I would have a problem with two user tempting to create the same cursor or reading the same. Everything works as expected.

Then I tried to change the cursor name to a static name, and it still work. I am able to run multiple same query simultaneously. Then I wonder, **is cursor bound to connection?**, and then d**oes PostgreSQL resolve concurrency by assigning cursor to session?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, cursors are not shared across sessions, and their namespace is private to their session as well.

Moreover, if the cursor is not declared "holdable" trough the `WITH HOLD` clause, it's automatically closed at the **end of the transaction**.

The relationship between cursor lifespan and session is detailed in the docpage for [`CLOSE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-close.html):

> Every non-holdable open cursor is implicitly closed when a transaction
>   is terminated by COMMIT or ROLLBACK. A holdable cursor is implicitly
>   closed if the transaction that created it aborts via ROLLBACK. If the
>   creating transaction successfully commits, the holdable cursor remains
>   open until an explicit CLOSE is executed, or the client disconnects.